# Java do/while loop offsetting first two questions

Tags: java, loops, boolean

I am writing a program in my programming class in java. The program is a simple do/while loop that asks some questions using scanner class and a priming read with a Boolean value. When the loop iterates the first time, it works properly, but when it iterates a second time, it displays the first question and second question at once and only allows me to answer the second. I hope this is clear. Anyone have any insight? Code:

```
      /*
      * Programmed By: Cristopher Ontiveros
      * Date: 9/19/13
 * Description: Compute weekly salary and witholding for employees
 */
package project.one.cristopher.ontiveros;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProjectOneCristopherOntiveros {

     static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String fName, lName;
     double rate=0, wPay=0, withholding=0;
     int option = 0;
     boolean badval = true;
         System.out.println("Welcome to the Pay Calculator");


     do{
        System.out.println("Enter employee first name: ");
        fName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee last name: ");
        lName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee hourly rate: ");
        rate = sc.nextDouble();
        wPay = (rate * 40);
        withholding = (wPay * .20);
        System.out.println("Employee " + fName + " " + lName + "\nHourly Rate: " + rate + "\nWeekly Pay: " + wPay + "\nWithholding Amount: " + withholding);


         System.out.println("Would you like to enter another employee? (1 = yes, 2 = no)");
     option = sc.nextInt();
     sc.nextLine()
     if(option == 1){
         badval = true;

     } else {
         badval = false;

     }
     }while(badval);


  }
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with your question but for the love of god start naming your classes better :p

Comment: @redFIVE the class is named <$project_num$name> I can see the professor liking that so (s)he can tell whose homework is whose when it's printed out.

Comment: Name your root folder of your project something like that, not class names. Comment blocks work wonders for adding stuff like name, date, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `sc.nextDouble();`, [`nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) reads only the `double` and skips the `\n` which indicates the new line (Enter key hit by user), so it'll be read by the next `nextLine()`!

You should "swallow" this new line by adding another `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: Better yet, never use `nextDouble()` and `nextInt()`. Just use nextLine() and `parseInt()`. For simple parsing I generally prefer to do it on my own, than depend on something else. `nextInt()` isn't entirely obvious what it does without reading the documentation

Comment: @Cruncher Yes We should not use `nextDouble()` and `nextInt()` methods until we have the inputs in a single line(separated by space) and after usage of them we have to call `nextLine()` .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `sc.nextDouble()` method .It reads next token of the input as a double and skips remaining.So you use `nextLine()` method when you use `next()` or `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` ,etc methods.